# Cordova plugin for support for cordova@7.1.0 and cordova@8.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-2.0.0

Facing issue with support of cordova plugin in multiple cordova version.

Under plugin.gradle file below are entries.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def doExtractStringFromManifest(name) {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile(name + "=\"(.*?)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    return matcher.group(1)
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile './src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = doExtractStringFromManifest("package")
    }
}
```

Facing an issue of AndroidManifest.xml file not found under cordova@7.1.0 version based code where code structure is having AndroidManifest.xml file outside of src/main folder in 'app' module

Facing issue will building project using 'cordova build android' and through file not found at path.

So how to support both cordova plugin from same plugin?

Comment: Which plugin are you trying to use?

Comment: Its one of my custom created plugin.

Comment: I would suggest you create a separate version of your plugin for Cordova Android 7.0.0 and above with the correct file path for the `AndroidManifest.xml`  which is `platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`